# Curve fitting a sinusoidal function

Tags: regression, curves

I need to fit the function $y = a\sin(\pi x)$ to these points: $[0,0], [0.5,a], [1,0]$ and another given point $p_0$. Please guide me through tackling this problem, because I don't know what to do.

Thanks!

Comment: What's $p_0$?${}$

Comment: It's a given point.

Comment: And that function is already done. All those points satisfy the equation.

Comment: @Shahar Except that I don't know the parameter a, which I need to find.

Comment: You'd only know from point $p_0$. Now way else.

Comment: Given $p_0 (x_0 , y_0)$ then $a=y_0/$sin$(\pi*x_0)$